# Programatically modify Azure Cloud Service configuration?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a c# API service deployed to an Azure cloud service. It uses various settings configured in the csdef and cscfg files, and I can update them in the settings section of the azure portal.  I have a need to programatically update some settings (to change a password, for example).

I know I can do this using PowerShell, but can I do it using just C# code in my API?

Answer (score 1):

See Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.ComputeManagementClient.ChangeConfigurationBySlot(...)